# Assign a specific string value to first Array position

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have a complex type JoinConditionOptions (it is a SQL conditional object), the idea is to have a never ending nest of arrays, objects and strings.
Those are current types and interfaces:

```
type JoinConditionOptions =
    | ConditionOptionsArray
    | OnConditionObject
    | string
    | undefined;

type ConditionOptionsArray = Array<JoinConditionOptions>;

type sqlValues = string | Date | Array<sqlValues> | null | boolean | number;

interface OnConditionObject {
    __or?: boolean;
    __col_relation?: ColumnRelationObject;
    [k: string]:
        | sqlValues
        | OperatorOptionsObject
        | ColumnRelationObject
        | undefined;
    [y: number]: never;
}

interface OperatorOptionsObject {
    like?: string;
    notlike?: string;
    rlike?: string;
    notrlike?: string;
    between?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    notbetween?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    in?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    notin?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    '>'?: String | number | Date;
    '<'?: String | number | Date;
    '>='?: String | number | Date;
    '<='?: String | number | Date;
    '<>'?: String | number | Date;
    '!='?: String | number | Date;
    '='?: String | number | Date;
}

interface ColumnRelationObject {
    [k: string]: string;
}
```

With that it is possible to do a complex nesting of Arrays, objects and strings with no problems.
Example:

```
[
    {
        id: [1, 2, 3],
    },
    'user.id is not null',
    {
        __or: true,
        name: { like: 'john' },
        year: 2022,
    },
],
```

That will output:

```
"(`u`.`id` IN (1,2,3) AND (user.id is not null) AND (`u`.`name` LIKE 'john' OR `u`.`year` = 2022)"
```

Now the problem is I want to tell typescript that on the first position of any array it can be a string: "__or". I want typescript to show that it is an option when trying to build that JoinConditionOptions object.

I tried to do add "__or" to the type ConditionOptionsArray with an interface merge:

```
interface FirstOr {
    [0]: '__or';
}

type ConditionOptionsArray = Array<JoinConditionOptions> & FirstOr;
```

But unsuccessfull (causing errors when compiling the example above: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'")

Any ideas on how to achieve this and maintaining the current features of the JoinConditionsType?
I am sorry if I did not make it clear enough, let me know.

**Edit 1**

Awsering @sno2: [TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QXm63agnyDWBLmG8Um+UW8YS+2ODSajTqeO+1OB8ARTTckuBCvJ0WZwFNzUALw7uB7zxrw+oTe5M-L-P7io3jfKLeLx+95-TqpH98AIQPruT5Xgef63u+wEXqBhYvhBb5sH0bBfH88CmOYjrOnY7KMAA0sAPDqKOda5GmRTEiecBcO+MY0gANO+FZ0YxnA0km3oMUxiYse+VbvFxbEVvxSCCfOyBiTSFYSax86LrJW6Saekn3ip8mAWeCmaewEj1OaEKofMawYQ6VjaiirrwFRAAUyiLMEAiEuwACUAj2Yg6wmRYZk6pZcAnsSpIcFAwAwEIUAfLZaowDwZgQNM7knkltIQLhMCMgAZBlBjuUBVEhMEcBZTlux5dchoxMQRXZWqln-N6RHWfZzn-CFxBCLgUUcN11lgCFsjtIkySpPRnzhXG-rOf5NQGN1fVyCUxheVh5m2JZBFEf8yDYMs4rqNZ2Dhc5sndVgwS3AYznKM5vT1Ga4AWnssV4HKrJIqtfz+Rq8pUB9urorymoKmllTkZGbDsIZ8CpbQfCvVqOpfTRbBwKjtL0gxcD9P0cAAOqXIVIVfCIIjvFVRzNFApwABZoIEKNozShKY6MjPoIkglo+6DNc6j9ICFoKysbzaO06EEACDS1MIJzIuCJgpMCEwMaS2LwQQDSyFcz0o2s6jyNy+jlOMtjeME3ARMQCTZOHPSNN03rcASDp7BAA) That playground contains my old code.
Here the "__or" string recomendation on first positions worked perfectly fine, but then I needed to add another key option to ConditionObject: "__col_relation", this new key is included on that [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYBMCWUngFwCkRLAYXGVXAHkAHYyGAXhgG0BYAKBlZgG8B9T0AG04BOAU14BDSug4ByJAimSpAVwhCBASTkBfTcwC6zZlACeZITGy4CiFGjDlKEGszYwAPjCtFb92xACCAgKiRs5s7iT4hDakAEYAVkLAUKGs7tACuADmKW4wiohCAGa4QggA3AZMxqYeUZQ+4P6BwTQwAUFGADwWkdb1FL4AfBVMhiZmEACOvABqoryKQo606Vm5ACLiZu7twZ1Ts-OLEIO5YIq8vLkxICC8QqJgZ4oAtjGqI8y4UKqFosBmCKeaJ2eKJWDsHLcEACAD8khudweYBGLm4fEEInEtnhtQWLzAACUsfUwUlUWw6ABrSSrMCZXToHIuNLTOYLJbMsIwciqcQwhqQEhk5IsFzcgj4okk7wirmpPIFYpgUoU1h0IySc5vVSMmAqgBuH2YOlGTG+v3+gNMQSgAoGjWFCSSHByvCQVKEuLpmTV+pAUHdnu9UAy9L9AiDXtpoayfrAAcjHujMB9fveUAA7kIhGBcbsugBlWP0546gQbLbDHIJqAZ7O5-PNIslzJl94V9ybH7VsWsXBNjqdYthtvubUdys9+MBgeSAvD1vt1RToS9lxSQZSXEjtbj16TrtbP1STrbyS70v78urk+DajnmCXsf6g8ro8-E+dB87pfXw8wN2Qhfluv6jsunaAceORSAAhD+F5-q+N4fsBMEIU+SETu+UGfialQWgIfwAnirzSmIpLOhCOTUjGo56mm+FMEAA), but I just cant make the feature of showing a string "__or" as an option on the first position of ConditionsOptionsArray and at the same time include the new key "__col_relation" in the ConditionObject. Any Ideas on how to combine both of those type structures from those two Ts Playgrounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tuple literal type notation to have a union of `"__or"` along with `JoinConditionOptions` as the first item then have a rest item to type the rest of the items as your `JoinConditionOptions` type.  Here is the solution:

```
type JoinConditionOptions =
    | ConditionOptionsArray
    | OnConditionObject
    | string
    | undefined;

type sqlValues = string | Date | Array<sqlValues> | null | boolean | number;

interface OnConditionObject {
    __or?: boolean;
    __col_relation?: ColumnRelationObject;
    [k: string]:
        | sqlValues
        | OperatorOptionsObject
        | ColumnRelationObject
        | undefined;
    [y: number]: never;
}

interface OperatorOptionsObject {
    like?: string;
    notlike?: string;
    rlike?: string;
    notrlike?: string;
    between?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    notbetween?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    in?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    notin?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    '>'?: String | number | Date;
    '<'?: String | number | Date;
    '>='?: String | number | Date;
    '<='?: String | number | Date;
    '<>'?: String | number | Date;
    '!='?: String | number | Date;
    '='?: String | number | Date;
}

interface ColumnRelationObject {
    [k: string]: string;
}

type ConditionOptionsArray = ["__or" | JoinConditionOptions, ...JoinConditionOptions[]];

const foo: ConditionOptionsArray = ["__or", { like: "foo" }];
const foo2: ConditionOptionsArray = [{ like: "foo" }];
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUg9gSwHYGE5ICYOA9B5MHdAZygF4BYAKClqgB8o1NtckCiliBBAJ14CGIanQZQ8qdFk54ARgCsIAY2Ai6jYsF7IA5mtqMArpggAzZBAwBuatVCQoxAI4AbAGoCXhiKTKOtumIAIgLA0Ix8giAAPM7unt7EAHxiSIYuLmKycHAuEAJIqYYAtrIQvDZU1MhhvKYCStASzNJscooqUADe+lAA+n1wvAD8AFxQ2bn5SJWiA0q5fbwQLqFsY0y5JUgASitr+ArKwLN0ANoA1uOa2kg6ALqjvaIarh5ePs-q4pCCwEMcNjEdrHL4GTZeYq7fYyI4qMFiYwYMwWay9M4gcZpUrlR5QJAQABu5UqAF9bFQauV6o0fuVQgDCECQZ0ejQ6C4EBcIBsbrpTrQkHBgJzubyAncBVBeKKedcJTopUKtLLxbdFb0ysAAO4QCBIDaRITRADKCqKON4wVCECSSuFWt1+sN-GNZvVFrKVsYITCdt6yBdUVN5sY2K91r99pwBvGRpi7sCYZKEZ9Nv97NoAHIklmNom7p7ypGIFKs9E8+MCzoi96oL7S70c2RK1Bq7WS2Xoi386H8Sni2mwl3c72PcnLZ2mwBCHtVvvhwf1m1ludthcDusNskUql1BrQNCQ6GrWEdYDddFXfzqvF8yXUclVKj2Q9SVj4JkkePkKBnABEAxDP+YjwMgLQfuwX5cAANFAAB0iFgZILAyNBxBnPc9yVNQCxcBepg5OMEFoZwPCuiAv4AUBvD-nBXRQLK4z-oRcAgaS2G4SQBE5AATMR76kUCP5+GcDFMVALE5Ox2FAA)

Comment: See [TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLCgZzAeSsgbwFgAoZc5AbQAYBdAfgC5kByAfTYHsoWBuUilVAATCAA9GIAK4BbAEbRazbFFABzZAB9kUkKJigIw-iQC+pUmACeABxQBhTnuBhgTnDddPMAQShQ4K2QAXmQ-AKsAHgBlMFUQNQA+ZAAyNAxsPBMLEgRvMGQYTk5mR2cvEA8K339AkKoWFmQAemaAUXBoZAALaBQ4PWRrO2R7ABUAJQAZZABqABpWFloTIA) Enter this playground, and inside the first String type CTRL +, see the recomendation "__or" that it gives? I want to achieve the same effect, but on my complex JoinObject.
In your playground it do not recommend anything, even with this tupple literal type.

Comment: @GabrielCunha I see a message saying "No code actions available." in your example.

Comment: [Example image](https://ibb.co/18tz9mD) I want this to happen.
[Your playground example](https://ibb.co/ZVPCtQd) And that is what is happening on your playground.

Comment: @GabrielCunha This is impossible because your type for `JoinConditionOptions` is a union which includes `string`.  Therefore, it is impossible for TS to know that you actually want `__or` because it could be any string.

Comment: I Just added EDIT 1, could you please give a look at it? I am saying that I have achieved that desired behavior but without one of the features from the current type structure that I have.

Comment: I managed to achieve the expected result. See my awnser

Comment: In the example of your awnser, if you change the lower case "s" from string type to an upper case "S" it will work just fine. If you change that, your awnser will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this with the code bellow. Note that the type "String" instead of "string" was necessary to typescript recommend "__or" as an option on the first position of the Array.

```js
export type ConditionOptions =
    | ConditionOptionsArray
    | ConditionObject
    | String
    | undefined;

interface ConditionOptionsArray extends Array<any> {
    [0]?: '__or' | ConditionOptions;
    [index: number]: ConditionOptions;
}

type sqlValues = String | Date | Array<sqlValues> | null | boolean | number;

interface ConditionObject {
    __or?: boolean;
    __col_relation?: ColumnRelationObject;
    [k: string]:
        | sqlValues
        | OperatorOptionsObject
        | ColumnRelationObject
        | undefined;
    [y: number]: never;
}

interface ColumnRelationObject {
    [k: string]: String;
}
export const isColumnRelationObject = (
    value: any
): value is ColumnRelationObject =>
    value !== undefined &&
    value !== null &&
    !Array.isArray(value) &&
    typeof value === 'object' &&
    Object.entries(value).reduce(
        (acc: boolean, [key, val]) =>
            acc && typeof key === 'string' && typeof val === 'string',
        true
    );

export interface OperatorOptionsObject {
    like?: String;
    notlike?: String;
    rlike?: String;
    notrlike?: String;
    between?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    notbetween?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    in?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    notin?: Array<String | number | Date>;
    '>'?: String | number | Date;
    '<'?: String | number | Date;
    '>='?: String | number | Date;
    '<='?: String | number | Date;
    '<>'?: String | number | Date;
    '!='?: String | number | Date;
    '='?: String | number | Date;
}
const OperatorOptionsObjectKeys: Array<String> = [
    'like',
    'notlike',
    'rlike',
    'notrlike',
    'between',
    'notbetween',
    'in',
    'notin',
    '>',
    '<',
    '>=',
    '<=',
    '<>',
    '!=',
    '=',
];
export const isOperatorOptionsObject = (
    val: any
): val is OperatorOptionsObject => {
    return (
        typeof val === 'object' &&
        val !== null &&
        val !== undefined &&
        Object.keys(val).reduce(
            (prev: boolean, cur: String) =>
                prev || OperatorOptionsObjectKeys.includes(cur),
            false
        )
    );
};
```